# Nuxt.js unknown store

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm new to VueJS and try to use the store with NuxtJS.

So, i want to get this (https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/) to work.

My store ./store/index.js

```
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export const state = () => ({
  temperature: '1234'
})

export const mutations = {setName
  setTemperature(state, payload) {
    state.temperature = payload
  }
}

export const actions = {
  getWeatherData({ commit }) {
    console.log("set weather to 123")
    commit('setTemperature', '123')
  }
}

export const getters = {
  storeTemperature(state) {
    return state.temperature
  }
}

export const mixin = {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([{
      myTemperature: 'weather/storeTemperature'
    }])
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      loadWeatherData: 'weather/getWeatherData'
    })
  }
}

export default mixin
```

Now i have a simple component to display the temperature:

```
<template>
  <div class="label">
    {{ testB }}
  </div>
</template>
<style lang="scss" src="./Label.scss"></style>

<script>
import { mixin as WeatherMixin } from '../../store'

export default {
  name: 'Label',
  //mixins: [WeatherMixin],
  props: {
    content: {
      Type: String,
      default: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    testB () {
      return this.$store.state.store.temperature
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I tried to use `mapGetters` and use it like:

```
testB () {
  return this.myTemperature
}
```

but this didn't work.

So i tried to use `mapState` via:

```
// store
computed: {
  ...mapState({ temperature: 'temperature' })
}
```

and use it in the component like

```
<div class="label">
  {{ temperature }}
</div>
```

But i always didn't get the default value of `1234`.

The Vue Console didn't find the store:

[image]

But forward to the NuxtJS documentation:

> Nuxt.js will look for the store directory, if it exists, it will:
>
> - Import Vuex,
> - Add the store option to the root Vue instance.

What i need to get the store working as expected and how i can access the store state properties? Did i miss something?

Comment: Just use `this.$store.state.temperature` since the exported state is in index.js of the store folder

Comment: You would only add the .store if you had a namespaced vuex module called store

Comment: @IsaacObella this.$store.state.temperature is undefined.

Comment: I see your calling your getters as `weather/storeTemperature` wouldn't that mean that the state would the be `this.$store.state.weather.temperature`

Comment: Yes, this was my first try to put the store into weather.js. But this didn't work too

Comment: In nuxt, this would be the directory structure for a moduled vuex app,

Comment: Create a directory called `weather` in store directory, then create files with names `actions.js` for *actions*, `state.js` for *states*,  `getters.js` for getters and `mutations.js` for your mutations and export default from each

Comment: @IsaacObella Your last comment, is very helpful to manage the store. i will use this in the next steps. currently, my failure was the last line in my store `export default mixin` removing this, and my store work as expected. With your comment i will arrive my goal also :-) so i can mark your comment as answer

Comment: It's also a good idea to create a root folder called mixins where you can place your mixin logic so you don't mix it with Vuex logic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200168/discussion-between-isaac-obella-and-rob).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To properly manage Vuex in NuxtJS, use namespaced Vuex modules, to keep your state logic properly organized.

For a globally accessible state, you can add these to the `./store/index.js` file, while for `namespaced` modules create a folder with a name of your namespaced module (Preferably no spaces.), then in this folder create files with names `actions.js` for actions, `state.js` for states, `getters.js` for getters and `mutations.js` for your mutations and export default from each.

You can then access the namespaced state with `this.$store.state.<NAMESPACED MODULE NAME>.<STATE VARIABLE>`